# Compress only specific files from a folder while preserving folder structure

Tags: windows-7, command-line, compression, 7-zip

Say I have 1 main folder and 10 sub-folders, each with .avi, .html ,.txt and .srt in them.

Now I want to preserve the folder structure but I want to only compress the .srt files into .7zip.

Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip
7z a archive.7z -ir!MainFolder\*.srt
```

reference:
`7z --help` or `7z`(without parameter)
[7-Zip Command Line User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/)

Comment: where do you get exclamation mark from? I can't see it in the user's guide, though I see it works with it

Comment: [here](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/include.htm) you go

Comment: Note, if your `MainFolder` path has spaces in it, wrap the whole path in quotes, otherwise 7z will just ignore your pattern and compress all the files.

Comment: With `7z.exe a -tzip metadata.zip -ir!.\*.xmp` I had "Too short switch/Cannot find file" error/warning. Added quotes to path and went perfect `7z.exe a -tzip metadata.zip -ir!".\*.xmp"`

Comment: You can also try `zip -r foo /MainFolder -i '*.py' '*.pdf' '*.tex' '*.doc' '*.docx'`