# How do I recursively compress only certain file extensions with 7zip command line?

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

With what commands can I compress only certain file extensions with 7zip? e.g. *.txt and *.doc and *.docx   (across subdirectories, so 'recursively')

I read [Compress only specific files from a folder while preserving folder structure](https://superuser.com/questions/1090727/compress-only-specific-files-from-a-folder-while-preserving-folder-structure)  and from there I can see that `7z a archive.7z -ir!.\*.txt`  would compress all txt files in the current directory, but what if I want to specify multiple extensions e.g. `*.txt`,  `*.doc` and `*.docx`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can repeat the `-ir` switch several times, like

```
 7z a archive.7z -ir!.\*.txt -ir!.\*.doc
```

(sometimes, just trying things out is the fastest way to get an answer ;-)