# Linux - compress specific files while preserving path and folder structure

Tags: linux, backup, compression, zip

So, basically I'd like to do this: [Compress only specific files from a folder while preserving folder structure](https://superuser.com/questions/1090727/compress-only-specific-files-from-a-folder-while-preserving-folder-structure)  but instead of Windows and 7Z, do it on a Linux and with native Linux tools (no root privileges).

I want to backup a very large directory (with lots and lots of nested directories) into either a .zip file (preferably) or a tarball. The file should:

- Only have files with specific extension and/or files smaller than some specific size
- Have the full folder structure of the directory I'm backing-up
- If possible, still keep empty directories in the backup (e.g. if a directory does not have any matching file, that directory is still created in the archive)

After looking around, I thought the following one-liner could work, which involves a command I had never heard about, `cpio` :

```
find /path/to/backup/ -iname '*README*' -o -name '*.py' -o -name '*.sh' -o -type d | cpio -pdm mybackup.zip
```

to backup all python and shell scripts, along with readmes and folder structure. However, the resulting `mybackup.zip` is in fact a directory and not a compressed archive.

So the one-liner becomes:

```
mkdir backup_dir
find /path/to/backup -iname '*README*' -o -name '*.py' -o -name '*.sh' -o -type d | cpio -pdm backup_dir
zip -r backup.zip backup_dir
rm -r backup_dir
```

This implies the creation of a temporary `backup_dir` as an intermediate step. A small price to pay since it does exactly what I want. The filesize requirement can be added as an option to `find`, e.g. `-size -10M` for files smaller than 10Mb.

But is there any better way to do this? Are there any caveats to this method or things to pay attention to? Or a faster method?

Comment: Use your `find` command to make a list of files (path names) you want in the archive, then feed this list to `zip`. Have a look at `-i` in `man zip`, in particular `-i@includefile`.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure exactly how this works. To what I understand from the man page, zip would still browse through the entire directory and only pick up files matching the patterns from `includefile`. Which would mean browsing twice through the directory (once with `find` and once with `zip`).

But it seems you can do `find /path/ -options | zip backup.zip -@` instead as a one-liner

Comment: `find /path/ -options | zip backup.zip -@` is the simplest option to to achieve everything you need in one go, without needing  temporary files.

Comment: Seems that solves it. Could someone post it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the files to be zipped directly into `zip` and get it to read then from STDIN by using `-@` option

Below is an extract from the zip man page

```
   -@ file lists.  If a file list is specified as -@, zip takes the list of input 
   files from standard input instead of from the command line.  For example,

          zip -@ foo

   will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.

   Under Unix, this option can be used to powerful effect in conjunction with the 
   find command.  For example, to archive all the C source files in the current
   directory and its subdirectories:

          find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@
```

So, in your case the command becomes this:

```
find /path/to/backup -iname '*README*' -o -name '*.py' -o -name '*.sh' -o -type d | zip backup.zip -@
```